# Can't install/remove, upgrade/update ANYTHING

Tags: apt, libreoffice, dependencies

I use OpenOffice, but got curious why so many Linux users and distributions are more into LibreOffice, so I downloaded it to check it out. When I tried to install it (a while back) I got an error message that said some conflict with files also used by Open Office was encountered.
Ever since I can't install, remove, update or upgrade anything.
I have tried the solutions suggested [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14562/unable-to-update-or-install-anything-due-to-unmet-dependencies), [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/packages-have-unmet-dependencies-error) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina) but no solution and things keep me running in circles.
Here's what I get when I tried autoremove, purge and autoclean:[image: autoremove, purge and autoclean]
And when I ran the fix-broken install I got this: [image: fix-broken install][image: cont. fix-broken]

And apt-get -f install:
[image: apt-get -f install][image: cont. fix-broken]

And trying to simply remove it: [image: back to square 1]

So I'm back to square one. Can't re-install or remove it, and can't ignore it either because it prevents me from installing or removing other stuff and even from updating the system (there are already 50 system components waiting in line in the AppCenter to be updated).

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

EDIT:

I downloaded OpenOffice from their official site short after I installed elementary, it never gave me any problem, and still works fine. It's the LibreOffice that's causing me all this trouble. I downloaded it from their site too (more than one month after OpenOffice, but I didn't install it immediately, and by the time I did -- and I don't recall this part so clearly -- I think I had learned already that it's in the repository and installed from there (or maybe I learned that short after installing the download version, I don't know anymore for sure). Anyway, the file I downloaded is still in the downloads directory and is called LibreOffice_6.3.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

UPDATE:
As Bo rislav suggested, I tried using aptitude instead of apt. Here is what I got:
[image: aptitude -f install]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version of Libre office you try to install cannot work together with the version of Open Office you have.  Try to boot into the recovery mode and fix broken packages from there. To achieve this, choose **Advanced options for Elementary OS** from the grub bootmenu screen, then **Recovery mode**. Connect to the network from there first, and after that choose **Fix broken packages**

There is something you should know - elementaryOS Juno it is based on Ubuntu 18.04 so most of the applications and solutions for Ubuntu 18.04 works also for elementary
I suggest you to try this one - http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/

or this one also:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I can't remove anything, it always bring me back to the results shown on the screenshots. autoremove, update and upgrade, all tried and none can be done anymore.

Comment: I don't know how you intalled open office, in order to give you the correct command, but if you use `aptitude` instead of `apt` you will have more control. For example try with `sudo aptitude -f install`. Then you will have some solution options and you can choose from these options. More info https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/rn01re01.en.html

Comment: I tried and got this: ~$ sudo aptitude -f install
[sudo] password for master:          
sudo: aptitude: command not found

Comment: `sudo apt install aptitude`  ?

Comment: see the screenshot on my edit from 3 hours ago (apended to the question).

Comment: ahh.. yes, because of this problem you can not install applications also.. Not quite sure that it will help, but what I can recommend you is to boot into Recovery mode (Advanced options for elementary os on the boot screen --> Recovery mode), first *connect to network* using the menu there, then try the *fix broken packages* command.

Comment: Just tried the recovery mode as per your instructions. Also didn't work. Apparently those broken bits prevent everything. I'm starting to think that I will need to remove the whole OS and reinstall it. Any suggestions about the best way to do it?

Comment: Try these lines before you start with reinstall -   `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/libreoffice` 
`sudo rm -rf /var/apt/cache/libreoffice*`
`sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Tried. The first two commands blinked very fast, I could not read what appeared on the top of the terminal, but there was no output. The apt install -f gave the same output as the ones in older screenshots. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101660/discussion-between-bo-rislav-and-joy).

Comment: Yes! This time it worked! :D I followed the instructions on http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/ and removed the packages that were always named on the error messages (see screenshots) and after that the autoremove worked and took care of the rest of the libre-office and now everything works fine again. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It was a great help.